# ReactJS onClick trigger does not fire itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React rookie here!

I've got a fairly simple component here, as a small part of an educational project:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';


class CoursesPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      course: {title: ""}
    };

    this.onTitleChange = this.onTitleChange.bind(this);
    this.onClickSave = this.onTitleChange.bind(this);
  }

  onTitleChange(event) {
    const course = this.state.course;
    course.title = event.target.value;
    this.setState({course: course});
  }

  onClickSave() {
    alert(`Saving ${this.state.course.title}`);
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Courses</h1>
        <h2>Add Course</h2>

        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={this.onTitleChange}
          value={this.state.course.title} />

        <button type="submit" onClick={this.onClickSave}>Save</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default CoursesPage;
```

My problem now is that when I click on the save button, the alert dialog does not pop itself up.
Until now I've got two theories about this:

- the `onClick` trigger does not work
- for some reason the alert dialog does not present itself.

Note: I haven't forgotten to bind `this` in the component class constructor.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your constructor you are binding incorrectly, there is a typo:

`this.onClickSave = this.onTitleChange.bind(this);`

should be:

`this.onClickSave = this.onClickSave.bind(this);`

Comment: Oh my god yes, how stupid and obvious mistake of mine! Thanks Molly!

Comment: No problem, easy miss. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the arrow function, like this:

```
onClickSave = () => {
    alert(`Saving ${this.state.course.title}`);
}
```

In this way, you need't bind this in constructor